# netCDF4 fill value behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, netcdf4

Running the following test code, give me some strange results:

```
import numpy as np
from netCDF4 import Dataset
array1 = np.array([[1,2,3]])
array2 = np.array([[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
rootgrp = Dataset("D:/test.nc", "w", format="NETCDF4")
rootgrp.createDimension("0", None)
rootgrp.createDimension("1", None)
variable1 = rootgrp.createVariable("variable1", array1.dtype.str, ("0", "1"), fill_value=-1)
variable2 = rootgrp.createVariable("variable2", array2.dtype.str, ("0", "1"), fill_value=-1)
variable1[:] = array1
variable2[:] = array2
result1 = rootgrp['variable1'][:]
result2 = rootgrp['variable2'][:]
```

result1 returns:

```
masked_array(
  data=[[1, 2, 3],
        [--, 0, 0]],
  mask=[[False, False, False],
        [ True, False, False]],
  fill_value=-1)
```

but I was expecting the fill value of -1 to be in all the values of the second row, as also the mask, with all Trues in the second row, since there was no data, like this:

```
masked_array(
  data=[[1, 2, 3],
        [-1, -1, -1]],
  mask=[[False, False, False],
        [ True, True, True]],
  fill_value=-1)
```

and result2 returns:

```
masked_array(
  data=[[4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]],
  mask=False,
  fill_value=999999)
```

but expecting a fill value of also -1, like this:

```
masked_array(
  data=[[4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]],
  mask=False,
  fill_value=-1)
```

What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score -1):

I believe the behavior comes from a misunderstanding of the way that a netCFD file stores its data. From what I can assume from your code, you're trying to create a file with that has two-dimensional data and then add the data to be stored.

A netCFD file saves, in addition to the values, the range of values for each dimension. These values must be saved as a 1-D variable as the name dimension implies. This tells the file how big the data is. The need to save the dimensions as variables is described in the [tutorial](https://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/)

It is true that one may use unlimited variables, as you have done by using the `None` in the `rootgrp.createDimension("0", None)` line, but those still usually have one dimensional variables, since you know they are dimensions.

In this case you can achieve the desired result by using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from netCDF4 import Dataset

# define the variables ranges
variable_array1 = np.array([1, 2])
variable_array2 = np.array([1, 2, 3])

# define the data to be stored
data_array1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3]])
data_array2 = np.array([[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])

rootgrp = Dataset("D:/test.nc", "w", format="NETCDF4")
rootgrp.createDimension("0", 2)
rootgrp.createDimension("1", 3)

# register the variables
variable1 = rootgrp.createVariable("variable1", variable_array1.dtype, ("0",), fill_value=-1)
variable2 = rootgrp.createVariable("variable2", variable_array2.dtype, ("1",), fill_value=-1)

# register the data
data1 = rootgrp.createVariable("data1", data_array1.dtype, ("0", "1"), fill_value=-1)
data2 = rootgrp.createVariable("data2", data_array2.dtype, ("0", "1"), fill_value=-1)

# add the variable values
variable1[:] = variable_array1
variable2[:] = variable_array2

# add the data
data1[0, :] = data_array1
data2[:, :] = data_array2

result1 = rootgrp['data1'][:]
result2 = rootgrp['data2'][:]
```

If you really have a case where you need for the dimensions variables to be unlimited, you will still need to add first the values you current have for the dimensions.

Adding the data directly results in the same bug as you are facing. To solve that, we can append the data with NumPy and then pass it to the file.

In this the case, the following code may help:

```
import numpy as np
from netCDF4 import Dataset

# define the variables ranges
variable_array1 = np.array([1, 2])
variable_array2 = np.array([1, 2, 3])

# define the data to be stored
data_array1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3]])
data_array2 = np.array([[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])

rootgrp = Dataset("D:/test.nc", "w", format="NETCDF4")
rootgrp.createDimension("0", None)
rootgrp.createDimension("1", None)

# register the variables
variable1 = rootgrp.createVariable("variable1", variable_array1.dtype, ("0",), fill_value=-1)
variable2 = rootgrp.createVariable("variable2", variable_array2.dtype, ("1",), fill_value=-1)

# register the data
data1 = rootgrp.createVariable("data1", data_array1.dtype, ("0", "1"), fill_value=-1)
data2 = rootgrp.createVariable("data2", data_array2.dtype, ("0", "1"), fill_value=-1)

# add the variable values
variable1[:] = variable_array1
variable2[:] = variable_array2

# convert the data to python
data = data1[:]
# append the data
data[0, :] = data_array1
data1[:] = data

# convert the data to python
data = data2[:]
# append the data
data[:] = data_array2
data2[:, :] = data

result1 = rootgrp['data1'][:]
result2 = rootgrp['data2'][:]
```

If you don't agree with me that the file needs to have the 1-D variables for the dimensions to work you might have found and edge case of the library, in which you may consider it a bug in the library, and you may want to submit a ticket in the [project's GitHub](https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf4-python/).

This was my workaround:

```
import numpy as np
from netCDF4 import Dataset

array1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3]])
array2 = np.array([[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])

rootgrp = Dataset("D:/test.nc", "w", format="NETCDF4")
rootgrp.createDimension("0", None)
rootgrp.createDimension("1", None)

# register the variables
variable1 = rootgrp.createVariable("variable1", array1.dtype, ("0", "1"), fill_value=-1)
variable2 = rootgrp.createVariable("variable2", array2.dtype, ("0", "1"), fill_value=-1)

# add the variable values
variable2[:] = array2
variable = np.full_like(variable2[:], -1)
variable[:] = array2
variable2[:] = variable

# add the variable values
variable1[:] = array1
variable = np.full_like(variable1[:], -1)
variable[0, :] = array1
variable1[:] = variable

result1 = rootgrp['variable1'][:]
result2 = rootgrp['variable2'][:]
```

Also if you don't need the dimensions to be unlimited:

```
import numpy as np
from netCDF4 import Dataset

array1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3]])
array2 = np.array([[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])

rootgrp = Dataset("D:/test.nc", "w", format="NETCDF4")
rootgrp.createDimension("0", 2)
rootgrp.createDimension("1", 3)

# register the variables
variable1 = rootgrp.createVariable("variable1", array1.dtype, ("0", "1"), fill_value=-1)
variable2 = rootgrp.createVariable("variable2", array2.dtype, ("0", "1"), fill_value=-1)

# add the variable values
variable1[0, :] = array1
variable2[:] = array2

result1 = rootgrp['variable1'][:]
result2 = rootgrp['variable2'][:]
```